# How to set null condition for integer column in linq query. Getting Null reference exception for integer column

Tags: vb.net, linq

```
  Dim payorProvidersList = (From pp In payorProviders
                                 Group Join p In accPayors On p.PayorCode Equals pp.PayorCode Into gpPP = Group From p In gpPP.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 Group Join hpc In hipaaPayorConnectors On hpc.ConnectorId Equals pp.ConnectorID And hpc.PayorCode Equals pp.PayorCode And hpc.TransactionType Equals pp.TransactionType Into gpHPC = Group From hpc In gpHPC.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 Select New PayorProvidersInfo With
                                    {
                                       .ID = pp.ID,
                                       .PayorCode = pp.PayorCode,
                                       .ProviderId = pp.ProviderId,
                                       .CreatedBy = pp.CreatedBy,
                                       .CreatedDate = pp.CreatedDate,
                                       .UpdatedBy = pp.UpdatedBy,
                                       .UpdatedDate = pp.UpdatedDate,
                                       .ConnectorID = pp.ConnectorID,
                                       .NPI = pp.NPI,
                                       .Order = hpc.Order,
                                       .TransactionType = pp.TransactionType,
                                       .PayorName = If(p IsNot Nothing AndAlso p.PayorName IsNot Nothing, p.PayorName, "Unknown"),
                                       .EmdeonPayorName = If(p IsNot Nothing AndAlso p.EmdeonPayorName IsNot Nothing, p.EmdeonPayorName, "Unknown")}).ToList()
```

Comment: You should tell us which line is causing the exception.

Comment: BTW, it is VB.net, not c#.

Comment: line 3. 'hpc.ConnectorId' threw an excpetion of type 'System.NullReferenceException'.

Comment: 'hpc.ConnectorId' is of integer type and is NULL in database for some records.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `hpc.ConnectorId` with `If(hpc.ConnectorId, 0)`.

**Edit:**

Based on your comments, your issue is not with integer field, but with `hpc` object itself.

Try replacing `hpc.ConnectorId` with `If(hpc is nothing, 0,hpc.ConnectorId)`

Comment: tried this but but getting complie time error, so used this If(CType(hpc.ConnectorId, Integer?), 0). But again getting same error.

Comment: What is the error @sujeet?

Comment: System.NullReferenceException{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: That cannot be compile time error. What is the compile time error you get when u use `If(hpc.ConnectorId, 0)`?

Comment: Showing compile error as -- First operand in a binary 'If' expression must be nullable or a reference type.

Comment: Again getting compile error - Value of Type 'ConnectorInfo' cannot be converted to 'Boolean'.

Comment: @sujeet : sorry, my bad. Updated my answer.